# Do ally kills count toward Phobos Junction?

Tags: warframe

One of the requirements for Phobos Junction on Mars is:

> Defeat 150 enemies in a single mission on Mars

Does that mean *I personally* have to get 150 kills, or just my squad collectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran a Defense mission on Mars to test this. One on my squadmates got 300+ kills while I only managed ~30 (Banshee is ridiculous at low levels) and I did not fulfill the 150-kill requirement for Mars Junction. The 150 kills must be your **personal** statistic, not the squad total.

Comment: yup, which is why I ran it during a solo defence or mobile defence mission. Lots of enemies to kill, they respawn rapidly, and you can always stay longer if there weren't enough.

Comment: Yep, found this out the hard way when my squadmate got over 300 kills in a mission...and I got 148.